# How to get some rows from 2 tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join

I have 2 tables and I need to get all rows from table no.2 that have the same key with table no.1.

Here is an example:

```
Table1                    Table2
ID  |   Name             ID |  Brand   |  tabel1_id
1   |   Razvan           1  |  Ford    |  1
2   |   Becker           2  |  VW      |  1
                         3  |  Renault |  1
                         4  |  Dacia   |  2
```

the result need to be an array:

```
array(
"Razvan"=> 
          array('Ford','VW','Renault'),
"Becker"=>
         array('Dacia'));
```

I  used right JOIN but not working;

```
  $resursa=DB::table('table1')
        ->rightJoin('table2', 'table1.d', '=', 'table2.table1_id')
        ->select('table1.*','table2.*')
        ->groupBy('table1.d')
        ->get();
    return view('home',array('resurse'=>$resursa));
```

Many thanks!!!

Comment: What have you done so far? Where's your code?

Comment: Please show the query you tried and that is "not working". Explain what you mean by "not working".

Comment: What does that mean its not working? What is the error?

Comment: Show me only the first element from table 2 that correspond table1 id

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment, so I have to write an answer:

there is a typo in your query:

```
 ->rightJoin('table2', 'table1.d', '=', 'table2.table1_id')
```

should be

```
 ->rightJoin('table2', 'table1.id', '=', 'table2.table1_id')
```

That would be correct, if there was a rightJoin function in the Query builder. But you need to use leftJoin instead, somethign like this:

```
 $resursa=DB::table('table2')
    ->leftJoin('table1', 'table2.table1_id', '=', 'table1.id')
    ->select('table1.*','table2.*')
    //->groupBy('table1.id') // you can't groupby to get the result you wish for
    ->get();
return view('home',array('resurse'=>$resursa));
```

Answer (score -1):

If I correctly understood your question, the correct query is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID=Table2.tabel1_id
```

To obtain the array you asked, I'd do something like

```
while ( $row=mysql_fetch_assoc(...))
{
    $array[$row['Name']]=$row['Brand']
}
```

Answer (score -1):

SQL :

```
Select t1.Name as colName , t2.Brand as colBrand FROM Table2 t2 INNER JOIN Table1 t1 on t2.table1_id = t1.ID;
```

PHP
Assuming you'll be getting an Associated Row.

```
$output_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
   if(!isset($output_array[$row['colName']]))
   {
       $output_array[$row['colName']] = array();
   }
   $output_array[$row['colName']][] = $row['colBrand'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT B.Brand) from table2 as B, table1 as A where A.id=B.table1_id group by B.table1_id.

you will get 2 row and fetch and use explode you will get the array